# HiddenFor on Partial View form contains no elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have a partial view which contains a form. I am trying to pass the lists in a hidden input element, so that when there is an invalid model state it can post-back properly. The issue is that the hidden input entities contains no data (it is not null it is just empty).

My parent view contains a view model containing two view models (1 for the child 1 for the parent)

```
public class UsersModel
{
    public CreateUserModel CreateModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserTableModel> UserData { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action (GET) for my parent view sets both the CreateModel and UserData and stores the `UserData` into a `TempData` variable, so that it can be passed back to the parent view in the case of an invalid model state.

My child view / partial view contains the following

```
@model APGame.Client.ViewModels.CreateUserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Users", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new {role = "form", autocomplete = "off"}))
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Roles)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Institutions)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.InvestigatorGroups)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Participation)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FamilyGroups)
```

And in the case of an invalid model state, my POST controller action does the following

```
var userModel = new UsersModel()
{
    UserData = TempData["UserData"] as IEnumerable<UserTableModel>,
    CreateModel = model
};

return View("Users", userModel);
```

Comment: Show your models. What are `Roles`, `Institutions` etc? They sound like collection properties which mean they will not bind

Comment: They are both IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: You cannot assign a complex object to a hidden input, let alone a collection of complex objects Look at the html your generating - each hidden input has `value="System.Web.Mvc[SelectListItem]"`

Answer (score 0):

I have always had to list out each property of the objects that I am attempting to do the same bind-back logic you are doing.

Thinking about how to shorten this up, you could try this in your view:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(m => m.Roles, "Role", new {@class="hiddenProperty"})
```

And make sure you include this CSS to hide those properties:

```
.hiddenProperty
{
display: none;
}
```

Or use jQuery to hide the properties:

```
$('.hiddenProperty').hide();
```